# Working with Linked Lists and .csv files in C, and one variable seems to be affecting the other for no discernable reason

Tags: c, csv, linked-list

So I'm working on an assignment that requires me to import a .csv file into a C program. The data (locations and details of picnic tables in an area) is imported into structs, and some of the elements need to be replaced with an index value that represents the material involved.
I've managed to get each line of data and parse it into a list of variables that I'll be populating the tables and database with. The first table that I'm creating contains the 'type' of picnic table that it is, and the code value that will be associated with it.
It checks if the passed value is present in the list, and creates a new entry for it if it is not. Part of this functionality has been implemented so far, but I've found a really odd error during my testing. The ID for the tables range from 3 to five digits, and I've found that when the ID is 3 digits long, two of the characters from the tableType is sliced off. When it's four digits, one of them is sliced off. When it's five digits, the code works fine. Obviously this is a big problem because it's comparing these values to already present ones within the list. I've scoured through every line in my code, and can't figure out what exactly is causing that to happen, especially since the two variables aren't supposed to interact with each other.

The .h file:

```
/*
 * You may add members to the struct below,
 * only keep it typedef'ed to DataBase
 */
/*
Define the structs typedef'ed to: 
Table, NeighbourhoodTable, PicnicTable 
as per the assignment specs
*/

typedef struct tableNode {
    int code;
    char *name;
    struct tableNode *next;
} Table;

typedef struct neighbourhoodNode {
    int code;
    char *neighbourhood;
    struct neighbourhoodNode *next;
} NeighbourhoodTable;

typedef struct node {
    int tableId;
    int tableTypeId;
    int surfaceMaterialId;
    int structuralMaterialId;
    char *streetAvenue;
    int neighbhdId;
    char *ward;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    char *location;
    struct node *next;
} PicnicTable;

typedef struct {
    Table *tableTypeTable;
    Table *surfaceMaterialTable;
    Table *structuralMaterialTable;
    NeighbourhoodTable *neighbourhoodTable;
    PicnicTable *picnicTableTable;
} DataBase;


/*
 * Take the name of a .csv file as parameter and create and populate the Database 
 * with the corresponding data set information.  Return a Database pointer/
 */
DataBase*  importDB(char *fileName);

/*
 * Take the Database pointer and the name of a .csv file as parameter and create a .csv file containing the 
 * information of the Database.
 *  NOTE: the exported .csv file must be exactly the same as the original .csv file 
 * from which the Database was created if none of editTableEntry or editTable were called.
 */
void exportDB(DataBase*,char *fileName );

/*
 * Take the Database pointer,  the name of a member of the picnicTable entry and a value for that member 
 * as parameters and return the number of entries in the picnicTable which have 
 * that value in the memberName.
 Pre: memberName is one of
 Structural Material
 Surface Material 
 Street/Avenue
 */
int countEntries(DataBase*,char *memberName, char * value );

/*
 * Take the Database pointer and the name of a member of the picnicTable entry as an argument 
 * and sort the table in ascending order of the entry values of that member. 
 Pre: memberName is one of
 Neighbourhood Id
 Ward
 */
void sortByMember(DataBase*,char *memberName);

/*
 * Take the Database pointer and, a tableID, the name of a member of the picnicTable entry and a value for that 
 * member as parameters, and find the entry which has that tableID and 
 * change its memberName value to newValue. 
 Pre: memberName is one of
 Structural Material
 Surface Material
 Table Type
 */
void editTableEntry(DataBase*, int tableID, char *memberName, char * value);

/*
Add a PicnicTable to  picnicTableTable as a new last entry

Param:
site is siteId 
t_type is table type code 
surf_type is surface material code
stru_type is structural material code 
st_av is street/avenue
neighId is neighbourhood id
w is ward 
lat is latitude
longt is longitude 
loc is location

Pre: if t_type, surf_type, stru_type, neighId do not exist in their tables, function returns silently without modifying picnicTableTable

Side Effects: picnicTableTable grown by one entry
*/
void addTable(DataBase *Db,int site, int t_type, int surf_type, int stru_type, char * st_av, int neighId, char * w, char * lat, char * longt, char * loc);


/*
 * print a listing of picnic tables grouped by wards in ascending order.
 */
void reportByWard(DataBase*);

/*
 * print a listing of picnic tables grouped by neigbourhoods in ascending 
 * alphabetical order.
 */
void reportByNeighbourhood(DataBase*);

/*
free all dynamically allocated memory
 */
void destroyDB (DataBase*);
```

The .c file:

```
#include "DB.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkTable(Table *table, char *value){
  
  Table *current = table;
 
  /*Check each existing value to see if it matches.*/
  while (current != NULL){
    printf("Current Address: %p\n", current);
    printf("Current Name: %s Value: %s\n", current->name, value);
    if(current->name == value){
      printf("Match found.\n");
      return current->code;
    }
    else{
      printf("Moving on.\n");
      current = current->next;
    }
  }
  /*If the code gets to this point, it encountered the end of the
   list without finding a match. Therefore, create a new entry. */
  /*  current->next = malloc(sizeof(Table));
  lastIndex = current->code;
  current = current->next;
  current->name = value;
  current->code = lastIndex + 1;
  current->next = NULL;

  return current->code;
  */}


DataBase* importDB(char *fileName){

  char *newTableType, *newSurfaceMaterial, *newStructuralMaterial,
    *newStreetAvenue, *newNeighbhd, *newWard, *newLocation;
  int newTableID, tableTypeID, surfaceMaterialID, structuralMaterialID, newNeighbhdID; 
  double newLatitude, newLongitude;
  FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

  //If file not found:
  if(fp == NULL){
    printf("File '%s' Not Found", fileName);
  }
  //Create the tables and Database
  else{
    
    Table *tableType = NULL;
    /*
    Table *surfaceMaterial = NULL;
    Table *structuralMaterial = NULL;
    NeighbourhoodTable *neighbourhood = NULL;
    PicnicTable *picnicTable = NULL;
    DataBase *DB;
    DB  = malloc(sizeof(DataBase));

    DB->tableTypeTable = tableType;
    DB->surfaceMaterialTable = surfaceMaterial;
    DB->structuralMaterialTable = structuralMaterial;
    DB->neighbourhoodTable = neighbourhood;
    DB->picnicTableTable = picnicTable;
    */
    
    char str[500];
    char *token;
    
    int count = 0;
    /*The first line of the csv files are the headers, so read them
      but don't do anything to them. */
    fgets(str, 500, fp);

    /*Run fgets until it encounters NULL*/
    while (fgets(str, 500, fp) != NULL){
      /*Parse the line of data into tokens, and assign each token to
    the table variables.*/
      token = strtok(str, ",");
      newTableID = atoi(token);
      
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newTableType = token;    

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newSurfaceMaterial = token;

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newStructuralMaterial = token;

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newStreetAvenue = token;

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newNeighbhdID = atoi(token);
      
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newNeighbhd = token;

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newWard = token;

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newLatitude = atof(token);
      
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newLongitude = atof(token);

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      newLocation = token;

      /*Check for the table type in the tableType Table.*/
      /*First check if the table is empty and equals NULL, if so
       then create the first entry. Otherwise, check the existing values*/

      if (tableType == NULL){
        printf("Created Table.\n");
        tableType = malloc(sizeof(Table)+8);
        tableType->code = 0;
        tableType->name = newTableType;
        tableType->next = NULL;
        printf("Address: %p\n", tableType);
      }
      else{
        printf("Called the function on Table ID %d with type %s\n", newTableID, newTableType);
    
        printf("Returned %d\n\n",checkTable(tableType,newTableType));
      }
    }

   
    free(tableType);
  }
  fclose(fp);
}   

void destroyDB(DataBase* DB){

  free(DB);

}

int main(){

 
  importDB("example.csv");
  return 0;
}
```

The makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c99

DB: DB.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o DB DB.c
```

I'm not particularly sure if there's a way to attach a .csv file here, so I'll simply paste the contents:
[The .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF4wo.png)

Comment: Attach a .csv file exactly the same way as you attach a code file, or a makefile. If it's big, just post a portion of it.

Comment: Note that `strtok` **does not** make a copy of the string that it extracts from `str`. All it does is return a pointer to some location within `str`. So the next time that you call `fgets`, the strings that `strtok` returned are overwritten, and lost forever. The easiest way to fix this is with the `strdup` function. `strdup` allocates memory (as if with `malloc`), copies the string into that memory, and returns a pointer to that memory. Problem is that `strdup` is defined by POSIX, not by the C standard, so you might not be allowed to use it. In that case, you'll have to write your own strdup